# Count of rows of based on a certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which is sorted by `sessionid` and `timestamp` `ts`.

What I want to find is, the count of `sessionids` which have atleast one listpage view `screen_name = 'listpage'` after a cart page page view `screen_name = 'checkout_cart'` in the same session `sessionid`.

Table:

```
sessionid screen_name ts

11 checkout_cart 1593
11 checkout_cart 1594
12 checkout_cart 1890
12 home_page 1892
12 list_page 1894
12 checkout_cart 1896
13 list_page 1900
13 checkout_cart 1902
13 home_page 1904
14 checkout_cart 1990
14 home_page 1992
14 list_page 1994
14 checkout_cart 1996
```

*Based on the table my count should be 2 `session id 12 and 14,13` cant be counted because `list_Page` is before `cart_page`
Please help me in writing a query for this, I am stuck with the logic.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation.  To get the list of sessions:

```
select sessionid
from t
where screen_name in ('listpage', 'checkout_cart')  -- only needed for performance
group by sessionid
having max(case when screen_name = 'listpage' then ts end) > min(case when screen_name = 'checkout_cart' then ts end)
```

To get the count, use a subquery or use a CTE:

```
select count(*)
from (select sessionid
      from t
      where screen_name in ('listpage', 'checkout_cart')  -- only needed for performance
      group by sessionid
      having max(case when screen_name = 'listpage' then ts end) > min(case when screen_name = 'checkout_cart' then ts end)
     ) t
```

Comment: thanks it worked, instead of max for checkout_cart i used min.

Answer (score 2):

Try this exists version:

```
select t.sessionid,count(*)
from your_table t
where screen_name='listpage'
and exists
(
    select 1
    from your_table t2
    where t2.screen_name='checkout_cart'
    and t2.ts<t.ts and t.sessionid=t2.sessionid
)
group by t.sessionid
```

Edit: added sessionid join condition, missed that at first

Comment: more or less this query is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sessionid, Count_Test = count(case when screen_name in ('listpage','checkout_cart') then 1 else 0 end )
from table_name
group by sessionid
```

... with this you dont need to do subqueries either. Its a simple aggregate with case statement.